# Sending multiple responses with Express.js per request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, dialogflow-es

I'm learning node js and I'm working on a bot with Dialogflow. I would like to set up a simple mechanism:

- step 1: dialogflow send a POST request with param1 parameter
- step 2: my application responds with a wait message (example: "your request is being processed") through a POST response in the form of JSON
- step 3: I retrieve the data from a REST API
- step 4: Respond to the DialogFlow's Webhood with a JSON

My problem (on step 4) is that I can't send two responses for the same request and I have this error message :

```
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774506+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774507+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774508+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774508+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774509+00:00 app[web.1]:     at searching.then (/app/index.js:89:21)
2017-11-03T12:45:00.774509+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

this is my code :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//middleware 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/webhook', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.result && req.body.result.parameters && req.body.result.parameters.param1) {

        // First response 
        var speechObject = {             
            speech: "your request is being processed",
            displayText: "your request is being processed",
            source: 'webhook-nodejs-api'}
        var json_1 = JSON.stringify(speechObject)
        res.send(json_1)

        // Second response

            searching_data_from_api().then(() => {
                console.log("return second response JSON")
                var dataObject = { type_pizza: "4 formages" }
                var eventObject = { name: "pizza_est_prete", data: dataObject }
                var json_2 = JSON.stringify({
                    followupEvent: eventObject
                })
                res.send(json_2);
                return res.end()
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    } else {
        var speech = "There is a problem. Try Again"
        return res.json({
            speech: speech,
            displayText: speech,
            source: 'webhook-nodejs-api'
        })
        console.log("There is a problem. Try Again")
    }
})

app.listen((process.env.PORT || 8000), function () {
    console.log("Server up and listening");
});
```

My question is, how can I send the second answer? I try with:
- res.write (JSON.stringify (data1))
- res.write (JSON.stringify (data2))
- res.end ()

But it didn't work. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why you don't concat the 2 responses and send the final response ?

Comment: You can't send multiple responses to a single request using HTTP, that's one of the basic concepts of the protocol: one request, one response. How long does it take to process the request (get the final result)? How are you submitting the request (new page load or Ajax)?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer.

The problem is that the data extraction takes more than 5 seconds
and if my bot does not receive the data in less than 1 second it returns an error (I can not modify the timerout at the level of DialogFlow).
I do not know how to set up asynchronous processing to send the second reponse through another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Dialogflow's built-in integrations, responses can only be emitted in direct response to an input from the user, so it will not be possible to respond twice to a single request.

If you decide not to use the built-in integrations, it will be possible to write some code that sends the original "your request is being processed" response to the user, performs the required processing and then sends a follow-up response by itself. You would do the following:

- Handle the incoming request from the user from whatever platform they are using
- Send the user's query to Dialogflow via the `/query` API endpoint
- Analyze the response from Dialogflow to determine which intent was matched. If it's an intent that requires your deferred processing to be invoked, invoke it.
- Send "your request is being processed" to the user.
- Once the deferred processing is done, send the response to the user.

It's important to note that you would be sending the final response to the user yourself; Dialogflow would not be involved.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Dan Imrie-Situnayake

That's exactly what I did. I use the functions proposed by the Dialogflow team here 

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/facebook

The problem I have is that I can not get the Sender ID from facebook message in DialogFlow and send it as a parameter to my Weebhook (because I use the FB Messenger as a channel) sent via the result .originalRequest.data. 

Any idea ? thanks for your help

Comment: If you're doing the integration with Facebook yourself and then calling the `/query` endpoint, the Facebook request data will not be present in the webhook request because Dialogflow never directly interacted with Facebook.

To get this information to the webhook, you'll need to add it to your request to the `/query` endpoint. See this StackOverflow answer for information on how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115004/passing-key-value-in-the-dialog-flow-request-from-client/47166252#47166252

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. 
So the only way to send specifics data from our webhook to dialogflow is to create a generic context ? 
What about "originalRequest" ?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include that in my answer :) Yes, you can provide an object in the `originalRequest` field when you call `/query` and it will be available in the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [followup events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events)

Basically, you need to respond immediatly, then load the data, and POST them to your bot.

See this : https://discuss.api.ai/t/fulfilment-using-webhook-takes-time-to-get-the-data/3726/7