# Passing key value in the dialog flow request from client

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to pass some key value objects in the initial request to dialogflow which maybe needed in the webhook?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

When you call `/query`, you can include key:value data in one of three ways:

- Include it in an object assigned to the `originalRequest` field.
- Include a context that has an object containing your key:value data in its `parameters` field.
- Trigger an event that has an object containing your key:value data in its `data` field.

You can find this information in the details of the `/query` request format in [Dialogflow's API reference](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#query_parameters_and_json_fields).

The values you pass will be available in any resulting webhook request. Context values will also be available for templating into your intents' responses.